# OpenGL ES glCheckFramebufferStatus return 0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am writing Android OepnGL program in native code.

The following code is called through jni, normal call, not inside any surface view.

When the glCheckFramebufferStatus() is called, the status is always 0.

```
GLuint textureA;
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1, &textureA);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureA);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

GLuint fboA;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboA);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboA);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        textureA, 0);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    LOGH("Single FBO setup successfully.");
} else {
    LOGH("Problem in setup FBO texture: %d .", status);
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Have you probed the OpenGL error state before/after any of the dozens of API calls leading up to `glCheckFramebufferStatus (...)`?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Hi, I checked the glGetError(), and no errors.

Comment: If I am reading the spec. correctly, there are only two guaranteed color-renderable formats in OpenGL ES 2.0 that have an alpha channel, `GL_RGBA4` and `GL_RGB5_A1`. On the off chance that you have a completely brain dead implementation, you might try using `GL_RGBA4` and `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4` for your data type instead of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` when calling `glTexImage2D (...)`. It should be giving a more informative error if this is the cause of the problem, but then again the spec. also says the only reason it would return 0 is if there was an error (`GL_INVALID_ENUM`).

Comment: Additionally, OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have a fixed-function pipeline. Your call to `glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)` should be generating an error, so something is really wacky if you really have `GL_NO_ERROR`.

Comment: Actually, let's start over; the only thing that makes any sense now is that you are actually running on OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1... I assumed you were using OpenGL ES 2.0 because your calls to `glBindFramebuffer (...)` are not suffixed with OES. Please include your OpenGL ES version in the body of your question and your extensions string.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Hi, thanks a lot for you answers. I use openGL ES for computation actually, GPGPU.  I just call a native method from Android Java code, then in this native method, I directly call openGL apis like:                                                      GLuint textID;
 glGenTextures(1, &textID);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textID);

Comment: So as I said, I use openGL for GPGPU, it seems I don't have a chance to set the opengl version.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem not because of fbo operation but related to opengl context.

I am using opengl es by native code in Android, I need configure the opengl context by EGL library.

So I need prepare the context properly so I can create fbo.